# Find the number surrounded by square braces using regex

Tags: regex

I need to remove all the numbers appearing inside square braces such as [9] , [2] , ....

This is my regex:

```
"(?:\[\d*\])"
```

Which is working fine.
But I am totally new to regex so let me know if is there a better regex that can be used.

[**Try Online**](http://regexr.com/3dgd4)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the grouping here, and also you'd want to match for 1 or more digits: `"\[\d+\]"`

Comment: that was actually my first attempt but i don't know why i made it complex BTW thanks

Comment: The problems with regexen is that they're easier to write than to read. Which means that for simple regexen it might be a good idea to start over instead of tweaking an existing solution.